# Adding special characters to a string

Tags: vbscript

How to add special character `_` in the middle of string? For example:

```
Dim x
x = "Smith"
```

I need to get output as: `S_m_i_t_h`

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
Option Explicit

' string concatenation (bad idea in languages with non-mutable strings)
Function f1(s)
  Dim l : l = Len(s)
  If 2 > l Then
     f1 = s
  Else
     Dim p
     f1 = Left(s, 1)
     For p = 2 To l
         f1 = f1 & "_" & Mid(s, p, 1)
     Next
  End If
End Function

' Array via Mid(), Join
Function s2a(s)
  Dim l : l = Len(s)
  ReDim a(l - 1)
  Dim p
  For p = 1 To l
      a(p - 1) = Mid(s, p, 1)
  Next
  s2a = a
End Function
Function f2(s)
  f2 = Join(s2a(s), "_")
End Function

' RegExp.Replace, Mid(,2) to get rid of first _
Function f3(s)
  Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
  r.Global = True
  r.Pattern = "(.)"
  f3 = Mid(r.Replace(s, "_$1"), 2)
End Function

Function qq(s)
  qq = """" & s & """"
End Function

Dim s, t
For Each s In Split(" a ab abc abcd Smith")
    WScript.Echo "-----", qq(s)
    t = f1(s)
    WScript.Echo "     ", qq(t)
    t = f2(s)
    WScript.Echo "     ", qq(t)
    t = f3(s)
    WScript.Echo "     ", qq(t)
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 39814484.vbs
----- ""
      ""
      ""
      ""
----- "a"
      "a"
      "a"
      "a"
----- "ab"
      "a_b"
      "a_b"
      "a_b"
----- "abc"
      "a_b_c"
      "a_b_c"
      "a_b_c"
----- "abcd"
      "a_b_c_d"
      "a_b_c_d"
      "a_b_c_d"
----- "Smith"
      "S_m_i_t_h"
      "S_m_i_t_h"
      "S_m_i_t_h"
```

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
 strString = "Smith"
 strleng=Len(strString)
 result=""

 if strleng<2 then
  result=strString
 else
  For i=1 To strleng
   result= result&  Mid(strString,i,1)

   if i<>strleng then
   result= result& "_"
   end if

  Next
 end if
```